# How to set properties using extended function?

Tags: php

I'm not sure if I worded my question properly.  I have a class who's job is to set up a list of definitions.  One of my functions is to set up some directory paths.  I'm not sure of how to properly extend to that function when setting up a new object.  See below.

```
class VM_Definitions
{
    public $root;
    public $ext;
    public $tsk;
    public $gbl;
    public $sys;
    public $sql;
    public $db;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];

        /*==============================
          COMMONLY USED FILE EXTENSIONS
        ==============================*/
        // Extension for include files
        $this->ext = '.inc.php';
        // Extension for database processing files
        $this->dbe = '.db.php';
        // Extension for task files
        $this->tsk = '.task.php';
        // Extension for global report files
        $this->gbl = 'global.php';
        // Extension for task files
        $sys = '.proc.php';
    }

    public function DB_Directory($root)
    {
        /*==============================
          MAIN DATABASE DIRECTORY PATH
        ==============================*/
        $this->sql = $root.'/db/';
        $this->db = $this->sql;
    }
}
//THIS WORKS FINE
$def = new VM_Definitions;
//THIS DOES NOT
$ms_Database = new VM_Definitions::DB_Directory($def->root);
```

Comment: Please refer to the official documentation http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php

Comment: VM_Definitions::DB_Directory <- This declaration is used for calling static functions, that is functions that can be called without initializing the object. You can't use this functions without initializing the class first which you do here: $def = new VM_Definitions; So the proper call to your function should be: $def->DB_Directory($def->root);

Comment: @Mark $ms_Database is a new object.  So you're saying I should do
$ms_Database = new VM_Definitions;
$ms_Database->DB_Directory($def->root);

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm saying. EDIT: But is there a reason you need two of the same object instantiated? You should just be able to use the first object you created and call it's method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the DB_Directory method to return something, in this case $this->db, which will be stored in your $ms_Database variable.

```
 public function DB_Directory($root)
{
    /*==============================
      MAIN DATABASE DIRECTORY PATH
    ==============================*/
    $this->sql = $root.'/db/';
    $this->db = $this->sql;

    // Return a value
    return $this->db;
}
```

Then access the class method like this:

```
$ms_Database = $def->DB_Directory($def->root);
```

**note** double colon (::) syntax is used for accessing **static** class members while an arrow (->) is used for accessing the members of an **object** (instantiated class).

Check out [PHP - Object Oriented Programming](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php) for an excellent OOP lesson.